# Outlook VBA Multiple Email Selections

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to get pull the information from my selection but I am having no luck.  Here is my code for a singleitem but cannot get it tow work with my selected items:

```
    Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
   Dim objApp As Outlook.Application

    Set objApp = Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
        Case "Explorer"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(1)
        Case "Inspector"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.currentItem
    End Select

    Set objApp = Nothing


    End Function
```

How would I turn this into to use a selection of emails?

Second Half Dimitry:

```
Sub Process_Email(oMail As MailItem)
    Dim MailSubject$
    MailSubject = LCase(Trim(oMail.Subject))

    If MailSubject = "Subject 1" Then
        Call Extract_And_Export_1(oMail.Body)

    ElseIf MailSubject = "Subject 2" Then
        Call Extract_And_Export_2(oMail.Body)


    ElseIf InStr(1, oMail.Body, "Body Field One", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

            Call Extract_And_Export_5(oMail.Body)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is declared to return a single item. How can you return multiple items from it?

In case of Explorer, loop through all items in the selection collection:

```
 Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
    Case "Explorer"
        for each item in  objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection
          MsgBox item.Subject
        next
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitry for your response. This would be correct in a standard case, however, I have been running into several errors on my subject and body screening side.  Here is more code leading into the messages.

Comment: So what is the problem? You need to be a lot more specific than that.